# SQL - Ignore reacquiring entries

Tags: sql

I'm need a way to take the first entry in a row and if the value in the second row is the same then ignore it and so on.
The field im looking at is checktype. So get the first I, then O then I whiles excluding the repeated rows.

**Example**

```
<p>USERID   CHECKTIME       CHECKTYPE   VERIFYCODE</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 07:50:32.000 I       0   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 09:17:57.000 I       6   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 09:19:31.000 O       0   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 10:16:32.000 I       6   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 10:19:44.000 O       6   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 13:41:41.000 O       6   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 13:41:46.000 I       6   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 13:50:29.000 O       0   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 16:03:00.000 I       6   1</p>
```

**And I need to return**

```
<p>2    2015-10-19 07:50:32.000 I       0   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 09:19:31.000 O       0   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 10:16:32.000 I       6   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 10:19:44.000 O       6   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 13:41:46.000 I       6   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 13:50:29.000 O       0   1</p>
<p>2    2015-10-19 16:03:00.000 I       6   1</p>
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LAG` to look into the previous record, compare CHECKTYPE and mark repeating records. Then exclude the thus found records.

```
select userid, checktime, checktype, verifycode
from
(
  select 
    userid, checktime, checktype, verifycode,
    case when checktype = lag(checktype) over (order by checktime) then 1 else 0 end
      as is_repeated
  from mytable
) marked
where is_repeated = 0
order by checktime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thorsten.

We were trying to write a whole function that already exists.
Work exactly as I needed it to.